# Automatically connect and disconnect to Bluetooth paired devices

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, xamarin, bluetooth

is it possible to write a program that can automatically connect, receive and send messages and disconnect to Bluetooth paired smartphone devices one by one (45 devices at least)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `flutter_blue` package

Check it at:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue

Comment: Tried it before and not working, I need smartphones to communicate with each other. Actually, I tried native code also but the app only connected to one device and then stop working (I'm developing booth client and host apps)